# jQuery: How to navigate from one td to a specific other td in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrow-keys

I am new to jQuery so I might approach this the wrong way but hope someone here can help me.

I have a pretty large HTML table that is created dynamically. 
To help the user I would like to **bind a navigation event to the arrow keys** only for this table. 
In this example I would like to **"jump" from on div to the next div** (they also have the class `"myClass"`). The table is larger than the example below but the structure always repeats so every third td has an (editable) div.

So far I couldn't get this to work but the function does catch the arrow press as I can show alerts this way.

**My jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#tblCalendar', function(e){
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37: // left
            // similar action to the left
            break;                  
        case 39: // right
            $(this).closest('td').next().next().next().find('div').focus();
            break;          
        default: return; // exit handler
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
});
```

**My HTML (simplified):**

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><div class="myClass"></div></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><div class="myClass"></div></td>
        // ...
    </tr>
    // ...
</tbody>
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rebuild your function a little bit. Now it would involves only one DOM request to collect all editable elements and stores them in a variable. You can rotate through all of them using the *left* and *right* arrow keys. If no element is selected, it gets the first one. I've added a class to [demonstrate that behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/pu09pdej/). To adjust this to your needs, simply replace `.addClass('active')` with `.get(0).focus()`.

**Example of the principal with a class that toggles**

```
var focusable = $('div.myClass');
var current = null;

$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    var next = null;

    if (37 == event.which || 39 == event.which) {
        if (null == current) {
            current = 0;
            focusable.eq(current).addClass('active');
            return;
        }

        if (37 == event.which) {
            next = current - 1;
            if (0 > next) {
                next = focusable.length - 1;
            }
        }

        if (39 == event.which) {
            next = current + 1;
            if (focusable.length == next) {
                next = 0;
            }
        }

        focusable.eq(current).removeClass('active');
        focusable.eq(next).addClass('active');
        current = next;
    }
});
```

**Reduced code when there's no class toggle involved**

```
var focusable = $('div.myClass');
var current = null;

$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (37 == event.which || 39 == event.which) {
        if (null == current) {
            current = 0;
            focusable.eq(current).get(0).focus();
            return;
        }

        if (37 == event.which) {
            --current;
            if (0 > current) {
                current = focusable.length - 1;
            }
        }

        if (39 == event.which) {
            ++current;
            if (focusable.length == current) {
                current = 0;
            }
        }

        focusable.eq(current).get(0).focus();
    }
});
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/pu09pdej/)
[Try before buy with focusable divs](http://jsfiddle.net/2h425kpm/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot - let me try !

Comment: The demo doesn't seem to work for me - I don't see a table there.

Comment: @keewee279 Only the two elements have content - 1 and 2 - you have to focus the iFrame on the right side and then hit left or right. :)

Comment: I like the approach with the class replaced the addClass two times with get(0).focus() but it doesnt work.

Comment: Got it - thanks ! :-) So it works in the demo now just not yet in my table. Do i have to adapt anything else other than the replacing two times ?

Comment: Thanks again - I forgot to update the first variable in your code, sorry. This  is awesome and works exactly as intended !

Comment: @keewee279 I've added a shorter code when the class toggle is not needed and only the focus is used. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `nextUntil` to find the next `td` with a `div` in it:

```
$(this).closest('td').nextUntil("td div").focus();
```

Although I'm not sure how a `div` can get `focus`

Since `this` is referring to the entire table, change the handler to watch for keypresses on the contenteditable `div`

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#tblCalendar tr td div', function(e){
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - that's exactly what I was looking for here ! If focus doesn't work here could I use .click() instead ?

Comment: Yes and it has the class myClass.

Comment: @keewee279 -- Try this: `$(this).closest('td').nextUntil("td div").get(0).focus();`

Comment: Thanks ! One more question, since I need the div, not the td, could I just say nextUntil('div') or do I need to add .find('div') in the above ?

Comment: @keewee279 -- You need the `td` in the selector, `nextUntil` looks at the next elements, so the `td` is necessary.

Comment: `this` refers to the table `tblCalendar`

Comment: @Mackan: Yes, it does.

Comment: Yes, my point is that `closest` will not work, since `this` is the entire table, not the div like this code seems to expect.

Comment: @Mackan -- Attach the key event to the individual divs then.

Comment: Not really my place to do so @tymeJV :) Just trying to assist in a solution that works

Comment: @Mackan: Thanks - can you say what needs to be changed here ?

Comment: @keewee279 I suppose you could use `.myClass` as selector instead of `#tblCalendar` (in the `on keydown` event)

Comment: @tymeJV: Thanks for this ! And then go with the get(0)... ?